# Compiling with g++ via linking .so file built by android ndk

Tags: c++, gcc, android-ndk, g++, googletest

I have a huge c++ code base with many library dependencies and there are Android.mk configuration files for building one single libGame.so by chaining all together. I am using this libGame.so on an android project successfully.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 as IDE for this c++ code base and successfully integrated GoogleTest and able to run unit tests on windows. Now, I want to run my unit tests on MAC-OS-X and it seems troublesome to create make files for compiling whole project with g++ compiler in addition to ndk-build process. I know hat g++ compiler can link ".so" files also as library. Is it possible to link any ".so" file that built by android ndk to g++ compiler?

I have tried to run the following command for one of my unit test classes called "LineSplitterTest".

```
g++ -I/Users/fuat/GoogleTest/googletest/include \
-I/Users/fuat/Development/Game/Sources/App/PlusGame \
-I/Users/fuat/Development/Game/Sources/AndroidNativeLib \
-I/Users/fuat/Development/Game/Sources/AndroidNativeLib/Libs/jsoncpp/include \
testmain.cpp \
/Users/fuat/Development/Game/Sources/App/UnitTest/LineSplitterTest.cpp \
libgtest.a libgtest_main.a \
-L /Users/fuat/Development/Game/Sources/App/UnitTest \
-lGame \
-o LineSplitterTest
```

But the compiler ignores my .so file with the following warning message :

```
ld: warning: ignoring file 
/Users/fuat/Development/Game/Sources/App/UnitTest/libGame.so, file 
was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) 
which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

I have changed my APP_ABI option as "x86" and built another libGame.so but nothing has been changed. I can not set "APP_ABI" option to "x86_64" because my google_breakpad dependency only supports "x86" and "armeabi".

In brief, I want to use ".so" file generated by ndk-build process as library on g++ compiler. I really appreciate if you guys have any suggestions.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to build your test executable - for x86_64 platform - against a `libGame.so` binary built for a different arquitecture.

Comment: Thanks for comment @AntonioPérez, how can I equalize architectures of ndk-build system and g++ compiler. I have built my so using "APP_ABI := x86" option and put "-m32" option at the end of my g++ compile command above. Warning message is changed according to this architecture change as follows : 

file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked (i386):

Comment: Sorry, but I have no experience with android-ndk. Try running command `$ file /Users/fuat/Development/Game/Sources/App/UnitTest/libGame.so` to check what architecture it is built for.